# I am trying to display my fetched data but got error 'map' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to display some data from a fetched api but I get an error saying TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined. Any ideas on how to solve it?

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const URL = 'http://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=tesla&from=2021-01-24&sortBy=publishedAt&apiKey=1306a4a63e0448ea86560c7eb7bd9df4';

const App = () => {
    const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        
        const todo = async () => {
            const { data } = await axios.get(`${URL}`)
            
            setUsers(data.artcles)
            console.log(data.articles)
                       
        }        
       todo();
     
    }, []);
     
    const renderedUsers = users.map((user) => {
        return (
            <li>
                {user.title}
            </li>
        );
    });
    
    return (        
        <ul>
            {renderedUsers}
        </ul>      
    );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: `console.log(data.articles)` and what does it print?

Comment: You've set setUsers(data.artcles), did you mean  setUsers(data.articles) ? and, what is the result of console.log(data.articles) ?

Comment: feeling like an idiot now. It was just a simple mispelled mistake. Thanks for prompt answers Nadia and Saba.